# Use one image as menu

Tags: html, css, image, menu, mapping

I want to use a one quite large image as my menu.

The menu text can be part of the image or on the picture somehow (dont know how to position it as text though) , the problem I have is that the picture is without fixed spaces, something like this picture : (cant use picture cause low rep :/ )

http://stack.imgur.com/ogGdp.jpg

The text will be inside these bubbles, and when I hoover them, the text should be in a different color and circled.

I was thinking to use image mapping, and use multiple images, each image has a different text circled, and colored, and switch between the pictures on hoover effect, but the image is quite big and I'm hoping there is a better solution?

I hope my problem is clear,

Thanks!!!

Comment: I dont understand what you are stuck with and what solutions you already tried. What do you mean by fixed spaces?
It is possible to crop image to several smaller ones or instead of bubble images use divs with border-radius:50%; Check this article for CSS3 shadowed cricles http://www.smartredfox.com/2011/01/rounded-shadowed-and-shiny-pictures-with-css3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better solution.  Image maps would do the trick here, sure, but if you want to add hover effects and fancy stuff you will be much better served taking advantage of modern techniques.

- The text: It's better to have text as text and not as an part of the image (the text *will* change).  Just put each menu item in its own `<a>`
- Positioning the text: Make those menu items `absolute`ly `position`ed, and you can place them wherever they fit your background image.
- Hover effects:  Having the text as text makes it easier to add those effects, change the color, etc.

Let's put some code where our mouth is:

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="link1" id="menu-item-1">Item 1</a>
  <a href="link2" id="menu-item-2">Item 2</a>
</div>


.menu{
    background-image: url(http://stack.imgur.com/ogGdp.jpg);
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
}
.menu a{
    position: absolute;
}
.menu a:hover{
    color: red;
}
#menu-item-1{
    top: 100px;
    left: 80px;
}
#menu-item-2{
    top: 220px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3pa1skqs/

Comment: cool tnx! it should work... :>
any nice way to know at what top/left to use in order to place in bubble or just guess and re-touch?

Comment: Guess and retouch, I'm afraid.